# Do you think it's advantageous to switch to Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, ado.net

With LINQ to SQL most likely going to not get as much active development as Entity Framework do you think it's best to switch to Entity Framework?

I've personally found EF to be very clunky and hard to use compared to LINQ to SQL which feels very natural.

EDIT: I recently posted an article on my blog about my feelings towards this potential decision...

[ADO.NET v LINQ to SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/chadmoran/archive/2008/11/09/ado-net-v-linq-to-sql.aspx)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

IMO, not at the moment.

It is clear (from [recent announcements](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/10/31/clarifying-the-message-on-l2s-futures.aspx) especially) that EF is in for some heavy revisions as the "[thunderdome](http://codebetter.com/blogs/ian_cooper/archive/2008/11/03/linq-to-sql-ef-and-the-thunderdome-solution.aspx)" scenario plays out between LINQ-to-SQL and EF. Whatever happens, EF (in a few years) will almost certainly look quite different to EF today. Or certainly "different enough" ;-p

As such, my view is: stick with simple. And simple is LINQ-to-SQL.

I don't see much benefit learning a notoriously complex system if I know it is going to change very soon.

And I'm 100% with you on LINQ-to-SQL ;-p

If I needed something more than LINQ-to-SQL right now, I'd look at [NHibernate](http://www.nhibernate.org/) or maybe [LLBLGen Pro](http://www.llblgen.com/).

(**edit** - as an update, my position has softened a little bit, [here](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/12/entity-framework-in-reality.html) and [here](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/back-to-coal-face.html) - but I'm still using LINQ-to-SQL as my primary tool; also - LINQ-to-SQL [isn't quite dead yet](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/02/linq-to-sql-not-quite-dead-yet.html) ;-p).

Comment: Right on!!! I love L2S, and I semi-hate EF :) (for actual, concrete reasons).

Comment: @Timothy - yes, there are reasons. People like Ian Cooper could talk *all day* about them ;-p (good chap, knows his ORM stuff)

Comment: Agree, spot on! When EF vNext and .net 4.0 is out, it will be worth taking a second look. Until then, L2S...

Comment: Unfortunately, MS has a habit of taking a data access strategy to 90% and then re-invents a new data access strategies every few years regardless of technical merit.

Comment: "Simple is LINQ-to-SQL (Server)"...  Hows that work with other database engines?  Not so well, eh?

Comment: @J Short: indeed for the question to even make sense, SQL Server must already be assumed. Note that there is also DbLinq for other providers (3rd party)

Answer (score 7):

I've completed a few MVC projects now in production with L2SQL under the hood and found it quite a joy to use. I'm now embarking on a new project and decided to write it using EF and L2EF given the previously cited articles proclaiming the death of L2SQL. After only a couple of days I've decided to go back to L2SQL. Simple things like having to set foreign keys for inserts using either the awful syntax shown below or uneccessary lookups have shocked me.

```
foo.Foreign_TypeReference.EntityKey = 
     new EntityKey("DataContextName.Foreign_Type", "Foreign_Type_Id", ForeignTypeId);
```

Rather than:

```
foo.Foreign_Type_Id = ForeignTypeId;
```

I don't think it will be that hard to port L2SQL to a future version of EF as L2SQL has a subset of the functionality (though better implemented). The few things that L2SQL has that L2EF doesn't, for example Single() and SingleOrDefault(), can be migrated to EF by creating a few extension methods. I think it will take far less time to get the system running using L2SQL and then port it over later when EF isn't so smelly.

Comment: That pretty much sums it up for me. I'm hoping EF vNext will be prettier.

Answer (score 6):

If you're doing database-driven development, EF has real advantages today.

I've used both LINQ to SQL and EF and worked through the many little frustrations of EF v1.

However, the one thing that made EF v1 win for me is the astonishingly good **update from database** wizard. Incredibly, this *actually works*! It may sound trivial, but if you're doing database-first design, you want to rely on tools to create your classes for you and you don't want to have to regenerate your entire model just to make a change.

This alone makes EF v1 my choice. I suggest ignoring the advanced features of EF v1 - it's nowhere near usable yet as the ambitious platform it aims to be.

Put up with the clunkiness of EF v1 and you'll be in the best position for the future.

Pete.

Comment: The 'good' 'update from database wizard'?? The one that won't detect if you change nullability, data type etc on existing columns? The one that replaces the entire SSDL portion of the EDMX when something is updated, overwriting any customizations you may have made to it?

Comment: (continued) The one that can't re-add a removed entity if you don't use an xml editor to manually clear out SSDL artifacts? Oh well, they say it will be better in Visual Studio 2010.

Meanwhile I'm sticking to L2S and updating my model using my sync tool for L2S models that apply changes *only*.

Answer (score 3):

I have to agree with Marc Gravell. *Maybe* when the next version of Entity Framework is released (.net 4.0 / VS2010) will there be an advantage to using EF, and by then it will probably be very different from the current version of EF.

Until then at least I will avoid EF like the plague for anything besides tests/experimental code that will never hit production.

The [EF msdn forum](http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowForum.aspx?ForumID=533&SiteID=1) is full of examples as to why EF is not ready for prime-time, but I there is [one particular example](http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3874607&SiteID=1) that is a clear winner - what would normally be a simple five table query (10-15 lines of SQL) becomes [>1500 lines of SQL](http://paste-it.net/public/q6ed5c2/) when using EF and the EntityDataSource control:

http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3874607&SiteID=1

http://paste-it.net/public/q6ed5c2/

And as to the future of EF - with Microsoft's [history of changing direction](http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=4100399&SiteID=1#4107623) on big strategic things overnight, who knows if their current "strategic goal" with EF will come true a couple of years from now..? I for sure wouldn't bet on it. See:

http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=4100399&SiteID=1#4107623

Comment: That 1,500 line query is ridiculous I can't believe that.

Comment: Yup, those kinds of monster queries are ... surprising. Here's another interesting example; simple query with grouping+aggregation on two tables. L2S generates an efficient query, L2E don't. 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/bb72fae4-0709-48f2-8f85-31d0b6a85f68

Answer (score 2):

For the record, some hesitation about the future of LINQ to SQL has been expressed here:

[Is LINQ to SQL DOA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252683/is-linq-to-sql-doa)

[Has Microsoft really killed LINQ to SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253263/has-microsoft-really-killed-linq-to-sql)

Comment: But my key point is: while there is so much flux, investing heavily is a mistake. LINQ-to-SQL requires very little investment, so I don't see that as much of a risk.

Comment: I agree completely, Marc. I'm just pointing out for those who may not be aware (as I was not until I read about it recently on SO) that LINQ to SQL is not without some risk. Low risk, and definitely high short-term benefits, for sure. You can tell by the volume of SO questions that it's very popular

Comment: Indeed. Gotta love the strategy: kill the implementation that people actually like ;-p In fairness, it is a lot more complex than that, and I do look forward to the "real" answer in a few years (.NET 4.0). MS have a bit of a PR/dev-confidence mountain to climb here. I hope they succeed...

Comment: ...because genuinely LINQ is one of the most ground-breaking, impressive and ambitious concepts that I've seen for a considerable time. It would be a huge shame if it was ruined by the fight between two competing implementations by themselves.

Comment: Amen, bro. Thunderdome, indeed.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ to SQL doesn't seem to be an option unless you use SQL Server (or SQL Server compact), so that was reason enough for me to avoid it and use EF (I wanted to use PostgreSQL).

There are definitely enough things missing in v1 of EF that would make me hesitate to recommend it. It sounds like version 2 of the EF (when released) would be the first version that could be seriously recommended for switching over to.

Comment: Spot on - l2s is ONLY SQL Server.  EF = other providers

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few experienced developers have given "[ADO .NET Entity Framework Vote of No Confidence](http://efvote.wufoo.com/forms/ado-net-entity-framework-vote-of-no-confidence/)" as is discussed further [here](http://blogs.zdnet.com/microsoft/?p=1457).

I think we're expecting it to be improved significantly in [.Net 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/10/29/update-on-linq-to-sql-and-linq-to-entities-roadmap.aspx) by the ADO.Net team.

And here's some [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL20/) from the recent PDC.

Answer (score -1):

Recently, i had to research which ORM project should use. At first - tried L2S. It wasn't bad at all, but it's already obsolete (MS won't support it anymore), that's why i started to check out L2E. I'm fine with generated code, but creating fake views, entities and mappings between them just to make stored procedure available not to fill all fields of entity was an overkill for me. And i wanted to separate my dataaccess layer, so - i had to map data from generated objects to ones i made.

It took me few hours of experimenting with NHibernate+Fluent NHibernate+LINQ to NHibernate
to stick with this combination.

Comment: This is incorrect.  Microsoft currently has 5 devs on LINQ to SQL.

Comment: aha... Yesterday read that they are fixing bugs. My mistake. Anyway - that does not change my opinion.

Comment: .NET 4.0 will have a bunch of improvements to LINQ To SQL

http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/01/linq-to-sql-changes-in-net-40

Comment: @Paul, i wrote this answer BEFORE that blog post.