# Using LINQ to get column value from column name when you have the row?

Tags: linq, dataset

I'm trying to convert some code that uses datasets to LINQ. Some of the code passes column names into other functions as strings.

Is there anyway I can easily rewrite this into LINQ?

```
string s = getElement(tr, elementName);

private string getElement (tableRow re, string elementName){
    if(tr[elementName] != null){
       return tr[elementName].toString()
    }
}
```

OR:

```
private void copy (tableRow trFrom, tableRow trTo){
   foreach (DataColumn c in trFrom.Table.Columns) {
        trTo[c.ColumnName] = trFrom[c.ColumnName];
   }
}
```

Answer to GVS:
The reason to convert to LINQ is because it in many situations are easier to code LINQ and get better performance. It's related to another question here on stackoverflow:
[programming pattern using typed datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295291/programming-pattern-using-typed-datasets-in-vs-2008)

The reason I need to use the column name as a string is mainly because the column names are passed as a ID for input fields, they are then sent back to the program using AJAX (jquery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use reflection.

Getting a value

```
private string getElement (tableRow tr, string element){
    string val = "";
    try
    {
        val = tr.GetType().GetProperty(element).GetValue(tr, null).ToString();
    }
    catch //NULL value
    {
        val = "";
    }
}
```

Or the copy scenario:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo c in tr.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    thr.GetType().GetProperty(c.Name).SetValue(thr,
         tr.GetType().GetProperty(c.Name).GetValue(tr, null), null);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. **Simple way**

   1.1. **Using IEnumerable** (Linq to Objects or similar)
   Change the elementName parameter for a Func and pass lambdas instead (you will get compile time checking as well!)

   1.2.  **Using IQueryable** (Linq to SQL or similar)
       Same, but use Expression> instead.
2. **Complex way:**
   If for some reason you need to keep the parameter as an string (maybe is introduced by user) You can use reflection to build an expression tree at runtime http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx.

   2.1. **Using IEnumerable** Then Compile, and use it as a parameter in a where, select...

   2.2. **Using IQueryable** Use it as a parameter in the where, select,

If you need to compose the lambda with other lambdas use this cool technique http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx

Comment: I think 2.2. Using IQueryable Use it as a parameter in the where, select, sounds very good. Any chance you could give me an example? I'm pretty new to LINQ atm.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you convert working and clear code into something using LINQ?

Edit: LINQ is nice, cool stuff. But don't make the same errors as many XML fans did (specially first-adapters), by applying it to everything.

Comment: Still I don't think the LINQ syntax will be as clear and straightforward as the code samples you have given right now.