# Thoughts on Entity Framework

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I was wondering what people thought about the decision to support Entity Framework over LINQ-to-SQL?  I have an application I'm developing originally in LINQ-to-SQL.  I found it the perfect solution for our application.

While attempting to port to Entity Framework I was surprised how rough it was.  IMHO, not even close to being ready for prime time.  No lazy loading, no POCOs, horrible dependency on inheritance.  I found it largely unusable in my case and instead decided to stick with LINQ-to-SQL until somehow this Entity Framework can get more polished.

Anyone else have similar experience with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is pretty much my view. See my previous reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276433/do-you-think-its-advantageous-to-switch-to-entity-framework#276439). This other question wasn't specifically about the problems in EF, but yes: it has a fair few glitches. For example (in addition to your existing options):

- no support for `Expression.Invoke` (re-using expression trees to form a more complex expression)
- no support for table-UDFs, which can be used to create well-defined, callable methods in the database that are still composable with sort/skip/take etc

LINQ-to-SQL handles both just fine...

Comment: Any thoughts on EF4? I'm curious to whether it resolves your issues with the original.

Comment: @Richard - I haven't (yet) had the opportunity to re-evaluate.

Comment: I have moved on to PLINQO to try to make up some of the gap.  So for, EF4 doesn't show much improvement.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on the application platform.  When my team set out to create a new ASP.net app, we wanted to go with EF... but after playing around with it for a bit, we went with Linq-To-SQL.  In a web environment, managing the L2S datacontext was a lot easier.  Also, we liked that L2S entities expose the original Id field (e.g. EmployeeTypeId), unlike EF, which would only have the child entity exposed.  In a web environment, a lot of times you really don't need that extra information, the Id is enough because it is a reference to a dropdown list that has already been loaded (and probably cached).

Comment: Not exposing the IDs was another issue I had.  Also, if you wanted to support many to many you had to design a table only with the ids and no other fields or it wouldn't manage the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

L2S is more mature for what it is made for.

And I will still consider EF as a BETA realease.

there is lot of discussion around EF, you can find alot more in related questions.

Answer (score 1):

I agree. There are too many bugs and design flaws in Entity Framework v1 (the .net 3.5 SP1 version) to make it usable in real-world development. EFv4 looks more promising though...

Answer (score 1):

I've heard that L2S is quickly going the way of the dodo. There is a little bit of chatter about a move to opensource - but the ADO.NET group at Microsoft is planning to push all their efforts towards EF...

Sad too, because I find Linq2SQL extremely easy to work with and the thought of porting all my code makes me a little sick.

[Update on LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities Roadmap](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/10/29/update-on-linq-to-sql-and-linq-to-entities-roadmap.aspx)