# How do get a simple string from a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

The following code does not work. There is only 1 row in this table. How do I just get the statement that the sql would return?:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStringArg);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select applicationname from tbl_settings");
command.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();
string simpleValue = command.ExecuteReader()[0].ToString();
conn.Close();
return simpleValue;
```

Okay any help on how to achieve this relatively simple task would be great.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since there's only a single value returned, you could do this:

```
 string value = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

If you need more than the first column from the first row returned, you'll need to use ExecuteReader().  See driis' [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960900/how-do-get-a-simple-string-from-a-database/4960929#4960929).

Answer (score 6):

The [DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) can't be indexed like that. You need something like:

```
using(conn)
using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) 
{
    reader.Read();
    string simpleValue = reader.GetString(0);
}
```

The general idea is to advance the reader for each record (using `Read`), then you can read values from the row. As pointed out in another answer, if you know there is only one single value in the result set, `command.ExecuteScalar()` gives you just that.

Answer (score 5):

You have to call the `Read` method on a DataReader returned from ExecuteReader to get to the first row.  Something like this:

```
        SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr.Read())
             ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd do e.g.

```
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionStringArg))
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select applicationname from tbl_settings")) {

        command.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if(reader.read()) {
            return reader.GetString(0);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For a single string you want to use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) to get a single value and then attempt to cast it to string.
From doc: *Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.*

Example:
`string result = command.ExecuteScalar() as string;`

For small stuff I often find LINQ2SQL the easiest to set up and use. [This tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) should get you up and running in a few minutes. For bigger projects [LINQ2SQL is considered obsolete](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=linq2sql+dead&meta=), see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364740/linq-2-sql-or-linq-entities) for discussion and alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Check [DataReader.Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.data.datareader.read.aspx) you need to call it.

Answer (score 0):

```
string applicationname = "";
using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) 
 {
    reader.Read();
    applicationname = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("applicationname"));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query_result = com.ExecuteScalar() as string;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query_result )) // do your thing here...
```