# Haven't jumped on the Linq bandwagon, what are your reasons for not using linq?

Tags: .net, linq, methodology

I seem to be in the minority, but to be honest I am not comfortable with linq and don't see any benefits in my personal development (not to say there are no benefits, just a personal opinion based on my situation).

I build web applications (.net, .net mvc) and I love having part of my data layer in stored procedures.  One thing I love about sprocs is that I can generate the entire db to script, then scan my queries, **readable queries** I might add, at a high level.

For those of you who don't like linq, what is your reason?  Is it just lack of knowledge/learning curve or is there a business case for not using it?

Comment: Can you change your question to better reflect that your talking about the Linq2Sql bandwagon and not Linq the language feature bandwagon?

Answer (score 6):

I actually *do* use Linq, but not for querying SQL. I use it as a really easy way of querying datatables to, for example, find the highest value in a datatable. Previously I would have used a for-loop for this code, but Linq makes it neater, and clearer as to my intent.

Once you realise that Linq is a general-purpose .NET query language, it's power and utility becomes much clearer.

Comment: False. The .net designation for this is LINQ. LINQ-to-X refers to the specific IQueryable<T> implementation/providers for X.

Comment: @Justice: You mean LINQ-to-X as in "LINQ-to-Objects"?

Answer (score 4):

So do you never do any handling of collections in your C# code? Finding the maximum value within a collection, or filtering, or grouping etc? I know I do these fairly often. LINQ lets me do this in a very readable, declarative manner (more readable than SQL, IMO - the order of the query is more logical).

Likewise querying XML with LINQ to XML, datasets with LINQ to DataSet etc. Oh, and not to forget parallelisation with PLINQ.

There are lots of reasons to love LINQ :)

Answer (score 2):

There was a helpful discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530/linq-to-sql-vs-stored-procedures) recently about whether to use LINQ or stored procedures, which includes the advantages and disadvantages of each approach.

And some people have concerns about the future of LINQ to SQL.

[Is LINQ to SQL DOA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252683/is-linq-to-sql-doa)

[Has Microsoft really killed LINQ to SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253263/has-microsoft-really-killed-linq-to-sql)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using LINQ for queries on arrays or generic lists. 
It's very easy to read and saves me a lot of typing for `foreach`-loops even if I go through multiple lists.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't bothered with LINQ yet as I haven't had any real need to.

Over the years I've learned to 'Learn-On-Demand' - new techs come and go so fast that you can waste a lot of time studying the latest trends, just for it to vanish the following year.

Not suggesting that LINQ will, as it seems to have had a good uptake, but I don't lose sleep over coding things 'the old way' as long as my design is sound.

Answer (score 1):

The original poster is confusing Linq (lambda expressions for queries) with DLinq(Linq for   lightweight databases) cause they are used almost synonymously by the community.

You can use Linq with any collections and use Sql like syntax on it.  Its pretty neat.

And yes, you can execute stored procedures using DLinq.  See link below

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/23/linq-to-sql-part-7-updating-our-database-using-stored-procedures.aspx

-RVZ

Answer (score 1):

We haven't been able to use Linq yet because we're still on 2.0, and haven't been allowed to upgrade to a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

I hate SQL, and have been using LINQ for the last year or so. I definitely prefer LINQ syntax over SQL syntax anyday.

Answer (score 0):

Using of stored procedure or Linq is your choice of course, both have pros and cons.

Basically as a pros for Linq you don't need to spend your time to create your data layer but in stored procedures you have to write a new stored procedure for each entity(maybe you could have a generic solution for that "stored procedure hell" but i think that would be complex to maintain). And I also think that the maintenance of a stored procedure is more complex than Linq(of course after you spent a little time with Linq.)

But as expected, getting data by using stored procedures is faster than using Linq.

And after the Oracle and other database support to the Linq will occur; if you still use stored procedure and you have to change your database or you want to support another database then you need to write Oracle and other database version of these stored procedures and I think then that will be a real hell, but not in Linq.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently creating software for Windows XP Embedded. I did a few spikes using linq and had to take it out because currently XP embedded only supports .Net 3.0 or lower, bummer. It wasn't much work but my code looked a lot better with Linq than without.

I havn't used Linq to SQL yet. I did try out a Linq to NHibernate beta and when that's ready it's definately the way to go for me when I have to do something with a database again.

Comment: Who says, if you have the bits for windows installer in your image, that you can't install 3.5 before you seal an image?

Comment: @Will. You're right it is possible. We're going to need to update the image quite often so I'd rather just target framework 2.0 than make this process more complicated just to be able to use Linq :-)

Answer (score 0):

I like LINQ. Its easy to read and write. I dont have to worry about my sql query optimization. Its a deferred operation which makes it more cooler. I can return IQueryable which is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The company I work for has one business case for not using Linq (to SQL):

They like stored procedures because they can be changed after deployment without the need for recompiling, reinstalling, etc.

Personally I don't really like this argument. Because so many people can (and do) make changes to sps at customer sites it can be very difficult to provide effective support.

Linq is a very good technology which makes a lot of tasks in .net very easy and efficient (dev time wise) to achieve. Also, Linq to SQL does provides a very nice mechanism for calling stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, lack of knowledge/learning curve (lack of time) is the problem.

Comment: Apparently I'm supposed to drop everything I'm doing to show MS some love.  :-)  I really like the concept of LINQ, but I don't see anything it offers that will make my current development easier/faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use SQL for querying databases directly (through stored procedures) and then use LINQ to do extra stuff to the data, for example grouping.