# Is linq2sql behind the scence equal to Entity Framework

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework

i know its a new thing , more powerful and a lot more options added to it,
but is linq2sql is part of the new EF ?

if not , what is the main different between the two frameworks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've written a couple of opinion pieces about LINQ-to-Entities, and its relation to LINQ-to-SQL:

http://www.hackification.com/2008/12/03/linq-to-entities-the-blackberry-storm-of-orms/
http://www.hackification.com/2008/12/04/linq-to-entities-follow-up/

Summary: LINQ-to-SQL isn't the same as LINQ-to-Entities. L2S has a small feature-set, but what it does, it does very well. L2E aims to cover a much wider feature-set, but the current version seems to have some glaring omissions (eg lazy-loading). v2 of L2E should be much better; the current version (IMHO) feels more like a beta.

Comment: Stu, I applause your well written blog entries! Absolutely on my list of recommended reading for anyone comparing L2S vs L2E...

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read and been told (repeatedly =) ), linq 2 sql is being retired in favor of Linq to EF.

See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253263/has-microsoft-really-killed-linq-to-sql and here [Is LINQ to SQL Dead or Alive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252683/is-linq-to-sql-doa)

EF will allow you to use a more generic backing store, and that is better for users of non MSSQL backing stores.

Comment: Microsoft's DP group _wants_ to turn EF into a replacement as of the next version (which unless I have misinterpreted something will be released as part of .net 4.0 / VS2010). Until then I can't see EF as a replacement for L2S.

Comment: Also see these two interesting recently published articles:
http://reddevnews.com/blogs/weblog.aspx?blog=2990
http://www.stephenforte.net/CommentView,guid,bc1bc043-3cdc-4ac2-8b46-3c72ad1d61cf.aspx