# C# Asp.net having arraylist to take in two or more column data of SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, multidimensional-array

I have a database that contain a table called `ResourceInfo`.

Inside `ResourceInfo`, there are 2 columns - `resourcetype` and `description`.

There is a global variable `protected List<String> ResourceType = new List<String>();` that will actually and eventually get pass to the ASPX file's javascript.

The following is the C# code.

How do I store the data from the 2 columns into the variable `ResourceType`?

```
            if (caltab.HasRows)
            {
                while (caltab.Read())
                {
                    ArrayList txtval = (ArrayList)[caltab["resourcetype"], caltab["description"]];
                    ResourceType.Add(txtval);

                }
            }
```

Comment: @ArsenMkrt The problem is that the ResourceType cannot add the arrayList `txtval`. The `txtval` is able to retrieve the database and the data in the 2 columns but `ResourceType` just cannot add the value of `txtval`.

Comment: I also change the code to `protected List<ArrayList> ResourceType = new List<ArrayList>();` but still could not get `ResourceType` to add the value of `txtval`

Comment: which version of .net are you using? can you use linq?

Answer (score 0):

If you planning to use arraylist, the following code should work. Arraylist is a datastructure which can only store values and not key-value datatypes.

```
if (caltab.HasRows)
            {
                while (caltab.Read())
                {
                    ArrayList txtval = new ArrayList();
                    txtval.Add(caltab["resourcetype"]); txtval.Add(caltab["description"]);
                    ResourceType.Add(txtval);

                }
            }
```

Also, I would recommend using LINQ instead of ADO.NET. There are many reasons why LINQ is better [What are the advantages of LINQ to SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593808/what-are-the-advantages-of-linq-to-sql?rq=1)