# Is Linq-To-SQL getting scrapped?

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

#### Duplicate:

> [Is LINQ to SQL DOA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252683/is-linq-to-sql-doa)

I read somewhere on the 'net that Microsoft is considering moving away from LINQ-To-SQL in its current form as it wasn't very successful.

I want as many opinions on this as possible as I'm new to .NET and  want to choose the best possible route for where I work.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252683/is-linq-to-sql-doa

Comment: i did search for similar questions but didn't notice anything. Thanks for correction on typo duffmo, I do no the difference just not fully concentrating

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, not LINQ per se. The "Language Integrated Query" is here to stay.

There's some talk about MS giving up on "Linq-to-SQL" (the SQLServer-only database version of LINQ) in favour of the ADO.NET Entity Framework, but even that's still a bit unclear.

See this post in the MS [ADO.NET team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/10/29/update-on-linq-to-sql-and-linq-to-entities-roadmap.aspx) and these comments here by [Oren Eini](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/10/31/microsoft-kills-linq-to-sql.aspx) and [David Hayden](http://codebetter.com/blogs/david.hayden/archive/2008/10/31/linq-to-sql-is-dead-read-between-the-lines.aspx).

And while I think Linq-To-Sql probably won't receive big updates anymore, I highly doubt it'll be physically removed from the product, so there's always opportunity for third-party developers to step in and make it great nonetheless!

Comment: The chatter I've heard is that LINQ to SQL will effectively be merged with LINQ to Entities.  Jury's out on whether that's a good thing...

Comment: I heard different things - even in the .NET 4.0 timeframe, there are still bugfixes to Linq-to-SQL being implemented - so I guess it'll stay around for a while, as a separate technology

Comment: The creators of StackOverflow adopted Linq to SQL as their ORM of choice.  Apparently they decided the benefits outweighed the perils.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly "scrapped", but MS is moving on to the [next big thing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx).

Also, don't confuse linq-to-sql with linq-to-objects, lambda expressions, or the IEnumerable extension methods.  Those aren't going anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

[Heres another SO thread that talks about this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252683/is-linq-to-sql-doa) They're not getting rid of LINQ, just Linq-To-SQL I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's extremely unlikely that MS would move away from supporting LINQ.  I'm curious where you heard it "wasn't very successful"... by all accounts I've seen LINQ is considered the best addition to .NET since generics.

For that matter, it doesn't "cost" anything to continue to support it regardless of how much it's used.  LINQ and its associated technologies (SQL, Entities, XML, etc) are here to stay.

Comment: will try and find the article that i read, but i thought here would be a good place to ask about it

Comment: when the SQL Server changes, it costs to make it work with other tools like linq

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is not getting scrapped, but Linq to SQL probably is: It looks like it will be superseded by the Entity Framework.

I assume that that will take some time, though I'd expect that MS will at least provide some migration tools to move from L2S to EF.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an MSDN blog entry pretty much hinting that Microsoft is preferring LINQ to Entities above LINQ to SQL, but no mention of scrapping LINQ altogether.

http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/10/29/update-on-linq-to-sql-and-linq-to-entities-roadmap.aspx

Answer (score 0):

LINQ will stay in the .Net-Framework since it's a very powerfull and popular Addition. But Microsoft announced to concentrate into the development of the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx). This will make the [LINQ-TO-SQL-PROVIDER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx) obsolete. But you can use LINQ to query data out of EF-objects, of course.

So I recommend you to take a closer look into the possibilities of LINQ, since it made Dataqueries to all sorts of lists a lot easier and faster (for me).