# Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is LINQ to SQL DOA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252683/is-linq-to-sql-doa)

I am starting a new ASP.Net project which holds all data in a SQL database. I would normally use Linq to SQL to do all my queries, updates and inserts. but as i recently found out Microsoft will no longer develop/support Linq to SQL. What would you use as an alternative?

Does anyone know why they are dropping this, as I have come to like Linq to SQL, and do you know what they will replace it with?

Any information would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Linq to SQL is not dead nor is it being replaced with EF**, they have not killed it, feel free to compare and contrast

- Linq to SQL
- Entity Framework (aka Linq to Entities)
- nHibernate or any other ORM

Pick one that works for you and stick with it, neither are dying.

FWIW, Microsoft has more developers working on Linq to SQL than it has working on MVC.net right now

I prefer Linq to SQL because I do not need to support non MSSQL db and its much lighter than EF.  It doesn't support every last thing you'd need, but in my opinion (and I may get flamed for this) Linq to SQL is to MVC.net as EF is to webforms.

EF obviously has its advantages over Linq to SQL though, there are somethings that linq to sql just flat out doesn't support (cross db joins, non mssql databases, creating a type based on a view, etc).  Every tool has its place.

Some decent [comparisons on the two](http://blogs.msdn.com/swiss_dpe_team/archive/2008/11/06/entity-framework-vs-linq-to-sql.aspx)

Oh and [StackOverflow was built with linq to sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/749358/what-was-stack-overflow-built-with-closed)

Comment: With Entity Framework 4.0 (second release), I really don't see any reason to continue to stick with Linq to SQL.

Comment: aleemb, you could easily say the exact same thing about WebForms and MVC.NET.  Some people prefer everything and the kitchen sink and don't care if something is lightweight or not.  I just want a very simple, lightweight ORM that does what an ORM is supposed to do.  I don't want everything and the kitchen sink.  I'm not knocking neither, nor am I knocking developers that choose one over the other.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft is now pushing the Entity Framework in lieu of Linq to SQL:

http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/10/29/update-on-linq-to-sql-and-linq-to-entities-roadmap.aspx

MSDN Info on Entity Framework:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx

**Update:**
More complete list of Entity Framework Resources:
http://blogs.msdn.com/wriju/archive/2009/03/10/ado-net-entity-framework-resources.aspx

And of course the obligatory O'Reilly book on the subject:
http://fyi.oreilly.com/2009/02/introducting-the-adonet-entity.html

Comment: alot newer info is out there on the topic

Answer (score 1):

**if you use ANY technology, prepare for it to eventually fall from favor, and not be the latest technology!**

if you don't pick Linq, whatever you use will eventually be "old", and people will be asking if it is worthwhile to learn or use, since there are better things out.

if you are writing software prepare to keep learning new tech and methods, or switch careers.

Answer (score 1):

If you like Linq 2 Sql, then I recommend you try out [SubSonic](http://subsonicproject.com/) as it works very much like Linq 2 Sql.  It's lightweight and your wrapper classes are generated from an existing database.  I believe the next version of SubSonic will be supporting Linq as well.

Answer (score -1):

Linq to Entities will replace Linq to SQL.