# Is Linq to SQL still a valid option?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm looking at starting a new project and one of the requirements I've been given is that the data mapping must have a very easy learning curve. Linq to SQL seems as straight forward as it comes. However, I'm getting confused signals from different sources about the project being killed. Some say it's dead, some say it's now part of the Entity Framework team. Does anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here (its not dead) [Is LINQ to SQL Dead or Alive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252683/is-linq-to-sql-doa)

I was at a talk by Scott Guthrie last week where he categorically stated that Linq to SQL is alive and kicking

Also changes for .NET 4.0 http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/01/linq-to-sql-changes-in-net-40 new changes to Linq to SQL

Comment: ...and ScottGu also tweeted the same thing just yesterday:
http://twitter.com/scottgu/status/4766070825

("LINQ to SQL is fully supported in VS10/.NET 4.0. Here is a list of improvements in it: http://tinyurl.com/linq2SinDev10 ")

Answer (score 2):

I would say that it most defintely is still an option. If it does the job you need it for then by all means use it. I would go as far as to say it is probably a better option to use L2S first (if you have never used an ORM before) and then upgrade to the EF later on (if need be) as it is a much easier jump than diving straight into the EF.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by all means - it's still here, will still be here and bugfixed in .NET 4.0, and will still be here for at least the foreseeable future (3-5yrs.)

Yes, the main focus and vast majority of efforts will go into EF - but Linq-to-SQL is still a great and absolutely valid option for small to medium size projects with just SQL Server as their backend.

Use it, enjoy it - stop worrying! ;-)

Marc

Answer (score 0):

It's 'dead', as in, Microsoft recommends to use the Entity Framework, as Linq2Sql is no longer developed. That being said, depending on your type of project, that doesn't of course stop you from using it. The learning curve of l2sql is lower than that of EF and thus, it can still be a viable option. I'm using it in my current project and, well, it works.

So, if the requirement is specifically 'it must have a very easy learning curve', then you still could check it out.

EDIT: oh ok, maybe it's not that 'dead', after reading some of the other links here. Reading Hejlsberg's comment that it will not 'go away' doesn't mean that it is actively developed though, but we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "data mapping" and "easy learning curve", you are missing the boat somewhat.  All ORMs have a learning curve.  Each ORM has it's own quirks, complexities, and challenges, including LinqToSql.

LinqToSql may appear to be the easiest to learn and use, but that appearance is very deceptive.  There are real challenges with LinqToSql that you will run into with any decent sized project.  Microsoft is not really enhancing LinqToSql, so it won't really get much better than it is today.  Why invest a lot of energy into a feature poor ORM like LinqToSql that has a cloudy future?

LinqToSql is not "dead" or "killed".  It's not part of Entity Framework.  Basically, Microsoft has said they have stopped significant feature enhancements on LinqToSql, but they plan to continue to do some bug fixes and support it for a long time to come.  Entity Framework is a different beast and that is where Microsoft says it is going to spend it's time developing new ORM features.

Trying to find clear, concise communication from Microsoft regarding LinqToSql's future is an exercise in frustration.  They really screwed up their messaging in that regard.