# LINQ to SQL. Any prospects?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Can you tell me, please, what prospects of LINQ to SQL technology?
Can I use it in my real projects, and for what kind of project I can use it (big or only simple projects, small db - about 30 tables)? Or it better now to use EF?
So, can anybody explain me?

Thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow runs on LINQ to SQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is LINQ to SQL DOA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252683/is-linq-to-sql-doa)

Answer (score 0):

It's not under active development by MS, but if you're using SQL Server, and Linq to SQL does what you need, then there is no reason not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Linq to Sql` if you want, however, the data access technology going forward from Microsoft is the `Entity Framework`.

`Entity Framework` does have benefits over `Linq to Sql` many of which you can read about on blog posts online.

As for who uses `Linq to Sql`, last time I checked, stackoverflow uses it as their data access technology.